# How to find number of steps to transform (a,b) to (x,y)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given 2 numbers a=1 and b=1.

At each steps, you can do one of the following:

1. a+=b;
2. b+=a;

If it's possible to transform a into x and b into y, find the minimum steps needed

x and y can be arbitrarily large (more than 10^15)

My approach so far was just to do a recursive backtrack which will be around O(2^min(x,y)) in complexity (too large). DP won't do either since the states can be more than 10^15.

Any idea? Is there any number theory that is needed to solve this?

P.s. This is not a homework.

Comment: Hint: x = m.a + n.b and y = p.a + q.b. What is the relation between m,n and p,q?

Comment: If it's not homework, why are you trying to do this? Homework-like stuff that isn't homework usually smacks of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Unsubstantiated accusations of homework are quite tedious. If you think there's an XY problem, feel free to downvote and move on.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: I wasn't accusing, I was responding to the "P.s. This is not a homework" bit. When something looks like homework, but isn't, it's often an XY problem, and I was trying to elicit further info about why they were doing this to see if they might be solving the wrong problem entirely. I don't think it's unreasonable to try to be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you reached some (x,y) the only way to get there is if you added the smaller value into what is now the larger value. Say x > y, then the only possible previous state is x-y, y.

Also note that the number of steps to get to x,y is the same to get to y,x.
So the solution you are looking for is something like

```
steps(x,y):
  if x < y: return steps(y, x)
  if y == 1: return x - 1 
  if y == 0: throw error  # You can't get this combination.
  return x / y + steps (y, x % y)
```

Comment: Wow I didn't think of something that simple. Solving the problem backward makes it much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, find the depth of a node in the [Calkin--Wilf tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree). The node exists iff gcd(a, b) = 1. You can modify the gcd algorithm to give the number of operations as a byproduct (sum all of the quotients computed along the way and subtract one).

Comment: Thanks for the theory link reference. Will look up to it!